# why input#name is coming in output?

Tags: javascript

i am working on a library project and the problem is with javaScript output .when the add book button is pressed the output given below is printed whereas the name ,author , genre should be printed .
see for example a  person put "abc " in name,  "john wick " in author and genre is fiction the output should be
`book {name:"abc", author: "john wick", genre: "fiction"}` 
whereas the out put coming is asfollowed.

output.

```
here is sjs.js speaking  
js.js:24  you have submitted library form 
js.js:40 book {name: input#name.form-control, author: input#author.form-control, genre: "fiction"}
```

html code

```
<form id="libraryForm">
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">name</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">author</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="author">
</div>
</div>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">genre</legend>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="fiction" value="fiction">
<label class="form-check-label" for="fiction">fiction</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="programming"value="programming">
<label class="form-check-label" for="programming">computer programming</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="cooking" value="cooking">
<label class="form-check-label" for="cooking">cooking</label>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add book </button>
<div>
<div>
</form>
```

javascript code is

```
console.log("here is sjs.js speaking ")
// function  constructor
function book(name, author, genre) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.genre = genre;

}

//add submit event listner to libraryForm
let libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
libraryForm.addEventListener('submit', libraryFormSubmit);

function libraryFormSubmit(e) {
    console.log(" you have submitted library form ");
    let name = document.getElementById('name');
    let author = document.getElementById('author');
    // for programming cooking and fiction ;
    let fiction = document.getElementById('fiction');
    let programming = document.getElementById('programming');
    let cooking = document.getElementById('cooking');
    let genre;
    if (fiction.checked) {
        genre = fiction.value
    } else if (programming.checked) {
        genre = programming.value;
    } else if (cooking.checked) {
        genre = cooking.value;
    }
    let bookobj = new book(name, author, genre);
    console.log(bookobj);
    e.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: `problem is with javaScript output`. But you don't actually say what is wrong with this output.

Comment: i have edited it pls have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Passing [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) to the constructor function instead you need to pass their value.

**Replace**

```
let bookobj = new book(name, author, genre);
console.log(bookobj);
```

**with**

```
let bookobj = new book(name && name.value, author && author.value, genre);
console.log(bookobj);
```